# VBA trouble with SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm using this code for an Access 2010 database, and I seem to have a problem with the syntax of my SQL statement, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to correctly format the statement. Thank you in advance for any help!

```
qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("Company_State_Q")

Dim strSQLSearch As String


strSQLSearch = "SELECT [Company Information].Company_Name, " & _
"[Company Information].Industry" & _
"FROM Company Information" & _
"WHERE [Company Information].State ='" & stateV & "'" & _
"ORDER BY [Company Information].Company_Name;"



qdf.SQL = strSQLSearch
```

Comment: Q: Are you getting any error message?  Q: Is there any reason you didn't put "from [Company Information]" in square brackets?  A name with a space in it like that can ruin your whole day ;)

Comment: paulsm4's suggestion is right, as long as "stateV" is giving the desired string then your problem is not having enclosed the tablename with [ ]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use ...

```
Debug.Print strSQLSearch
```

... in your code after you build the `strSQLSearch` string.  You can then view the string in the Immediate window (go there with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>).

From the Immediate window I set the value of `stateV` to "CA" and tested your string like this:

```
stateV = "CA" : ? "SELECT [Company Information].Company_Name, " & _
"[Company Information].Industry" & _
"FROM Company Information" & _
"WHERE [Company Information].State ='" & stateV & "'" & _
"ORDER BY [Company Information].Company_Name;"
SELECT [Company Information].Company_Name, [Company Information].IndustryFROM Company InformationWHERE [Company Information].State ='CA'ORDER BY [Company Information].Company_Name;
```

Once you actually see the completed `strSQLSearch` string, it's easy to spot  multiple problems:

1. `IndustryFROM` should be `Industry FROM`
2. `FROM Company Information` should be `FROM [Company Information]`
3. `InformationWHERE` should be `Information WHERE`
4. `'CA'ORDER` should be `'CA' ORDER`

Consider using line breaks between the sections of your `SELECT` statement.  The db engine is perfectly happy with line breaks instead of spaces.  And you may find it easier to read the statement as several short lines rather than as one long line.

```
Dim strSQLSearch As String
strSQLSearch = "SELECT ci.Company_Name, ci.Industry" & vbCrLf & _
    "FROM [Company Information] AS ci" & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE ci.State ='" & stateV & "'" & vbCrLf & _
    "ORDER BY ci.Company_Name;"
Debug.Print strSQLSearch
```

Also at the beginning of your code you have ...

```
qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("Company_State_Q")
```

It seems `qdf` must be a DAO.QueryDef object, so I think you should use the `Set` keyword to assign to it.

```
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("Company_State_Q")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Also, thank you for not just posting the correct response but explaining it as well. You know what they say about teaching a man to fish...